# Прокрутка активности вниз

Tags: java, android, activity, textview

На активности в `TextView` передается довольно большой объем текста. Когда его становится слишком много он уходит "вниз", но активность прокрутить вниз нельзя. Как сделать так, что бы можно было прокручивать вниз?

Comment: использовать `ScrollView` например. Либо можно так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/5898409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так, как вариант:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Только `android:layout_weight` тут не будет работать, так как механизм присвоения весов для дочерних элементов поддерживает только `LinearLayout`

Comment: можно layout поместить в NestedScrollView